# Need explanation on these bits of codes

Tags: c#, sliding-tile-puzzle

i have recently stumbled upon a project(8-puzzle solver using A* alg) in which some codes are weird to me , because i have never seen the likes of it before .

what does this line mean ? what is this ?!

```
this[StateIndex]
```

whats this notation ? i cant undersand it at all !
i posted a sample of the class so that you can see it almost all together . 
and one more question , is it not wrong to have a class implemented like StateNode? it used only a constructor to initialize its fields , and yet worst, declared them all public ! should he/she not have implemented Propertise for this task?

```
public enum Direction 
{
    Up = 1, Down = 2, Left = 3, Right = 4, UpUp = 5, DownDown = 6, LeftLeft = 7, RightRight = 8, Stop = 9
}

class StateNode
{
    public int Parent;
    public List<int> Childs;
    public Direction Move;
    public Direction ParentMove;
    public byte[,] State;
    public byte Depth;
    public byte NullRow;
    public byte NullCol;
public StateNode()
{ }
public StateNode(int NewParent, Direction NewMove, Direction ParentMove, byte NewDepth, byte NewNullRow, byte NewNullCol)
{
    this.Parent = NewParent;
    this.State = new byte[5, 5];
    this.Move = NewMove;
    this.ParentMove = ParentMove;
    this.Depth = NewDepth;
    this.NullRow = NewNullRow;
    this.NullCol = NewNullCol;
    this.Childs = new List<int>();
}
}

class StateTree : List<StateNode>
{
    public static long MakedNodes;
    public static long CheckedNodes;
    public static byte MaxDepth;

    public List<int> Successor1(int StateIndex)
    {
        List<int> RetNodes = new List<int>();
        StateNode NewState = new StateNode();

        //Up
    if (this[StateIndex].NullRow + 1 <= 3 && this[StateIndex].ParentMove != Direction.Up)
    {
        NewState = ChangeItemState(this[StateIndex], StateIndex, Direction.Up, Direction.Down, Convert.ToByte(this[StateIndex].Depth + 1), this[StateIndex].NullRow, this[StateIndex].NullCol, Convert.ToByte(this[StateIndex].NullRow + 1), this[StateIndex].NullCol);

        this.Add(NewState);
        RetNodes.Add(this.Count - 1);
        StateTree.MakedNodes++;
        this[StateIndex].Childs.Add(this.Count - 1);
        if (NewState.Depth > StateTree.MaxDepth)
            StateTree.MaxDepth = NewState.Depth;

    }
    //Down
    //Left
    //Right

    return RetNodes;
}
}
```

Comment: You don't really have to post the whole code if you only have trouble understanding a specific syntax. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but `StateIndex` is used as an index in `this`. It will retrieve the item positioned at that position in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this[StateIndex]` is using the current class' indexer property.  The indexer property is what allows you to access an element in a collection or list object as if it was an array.  For instance:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("Item 1");
strings.Add("Item 2");
strings.Add("Item 3");
string x = strings[0];  // Returns the first item in the list ("Item 1")
```

When you want to access the indexer property of your own class, however, you have to preface it with the `this` keyword.  You'll notice that in your example, the `StateTree` class doesn't implement an indexer property, so that may be adding to your confusion.  The reason it works is because `StateTree` inherits from `List<StateNode>` which does implement an indexer property.

But don't get confused between classes with indexer properties and arrays.  Arrays are a completely different thing, though the syntax is similar.  An array is a list of objects which can be accessed by an index.  An indexer property is an unnamed property of a single object that acts as an array.  So for instance, `List<string>` has an indexer property, so you can access the items it contains using the same syntax as an array index (as shown in the above example).  However, you can still make an array of `List<string>` objects.  So for instance:

```
List<string> strings1 = new List<string>();
strings1.Add("Item 1.1");
strings1.Add("Item 1.2");

List<string> strings2 = new List<string>();
strings2.Add("Item 2.1");
strings2.Add("Item 2.2");

List<string>[] stringsArray = new List<string>[] { strings1, strings2 };
object result;
result = stringsArray[0];  // Returns strings1
result = stringsArray[0][1];  // Returns "Item 1.2"
result = stringsArray[1][0];  // Returns "Item 2.1"
```

As far as `StateNode` goes, there's nothing technically wrong with it, and it's not unusual to have a constructor that initializes all the field values, but it's always better to use properties instead of public fields.

Comment: Thank you very much ( and also everyone else that helped :) ) 
Ok , lets see if i got this right . if i declare a class with out an indexer  , i cant have sth like :
MyClass[] myclass = new MyClass[5]; 
right ? in order to be able to do that i need to use the approaches like these right? !

Comment: i got confused , in all samples i have seen about indexers, there is already an object created! and then , that object gets indexed! there is no object yet declared in this class! :
see the examples here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/senthurganesh/109172007050741AM/1.aspx 
---------------------
class ParentClass

    {

        private string[] range = new string[5];

        public string this[int indexrange]

        {

            get {return range[indexrange];}

            set {range[indexrange] = value; }

        }

Comment: @Hossein I updated my answer to hopefully answer your second question.

Answer (score 3):

In your *concrete case* it's just access to the element, as it used inside the class that is **derived** from the `List<T>`

But it can be also [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) which enables index acces to your class object.

For example declare class like this:

```
public class ListWrapper
{
    private List<int> list = ...

    public int this[int index]
    {
        return list[index];
    }
}
```

and after use it like

```
var lw = new ListWrapper(); 
//fill it with data 

int a = lw[2]; //ACCESS WITH INDEX EVEN IF THE TYPE IS NOT COLLECTION BY ITSELF
```

Answer (score 2):

its `Indexed Properties` in C# .net .

you can check Tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx check here

Answer (score 1):

`this[StateIndex]` is pointing to an element within the class. Because `StateTree` inherits from a `List<T>`, you have a collection that's accessible by index (in this case `this[N]` where `N` is the element's index.

Answer (score 1):

this[StateIndex] is how you give a class and indexed property e.g

```
public class IndexedClass
{
  private List<String> _content;
  public IndexedClass()
  {
     _content = new List<String>();
  }
  public Add(String argValue)
  {
     _content.Add(argValue);
  }

  public string this[int index]
  {
     get
     {
        return _content[index];
     }
     set
     {
         _content[Index] = value;
     }
  }
}
```

so now you can do

```
IndexedClass myIndex = new IndexedClass();
myIndex.Add("Fred");
Console.Writeline(myIndex[0]);
myIndex[0] = "Bill";
Console.Writeline(myIndex[0]);
```

As for statenode if it's local to the class (a helper) then you could argue it as okay, I don't like it though, another ten minutes work it could be done properly. If it's public in the assembly, then it's not accpetable in my opinion. But that is an opinion.